# gulp sourcemaps not writing expected sourcemap

Tags: gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

Here is the task:

```
dev.assets.sass = [
            'client/modules/*[!public]*/scss/*.scss'
        ];

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(dev.assets.sass)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(concat('application.min.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/build'));
});
```

The issue is that the source map looks like this:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["../../stdin"]....
```

which is not what I expected. I would like something similar to bootstrap, where, in the chrome developer a style is mapped back to its original less source. My sourcemaps are just mapping back to stdin which I assume is the result of the sass pipe. I think gulp-sourcemaps is only creating the map for the last operation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `gulp-sass` to version **2.1.1**. This was a bug in `gulp-sass` that was fixed with the latest release.

Source: https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/394